# Determining which implementation to inject at runtime using .NET Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have three types of users in my application, let's say `Type1, Type2 and Type3`.
Then i want to create one service implementation for each type, let's say i have a service to get photos, i would have three services : `Type1PhotosService, Type2PhotosService and Type3PhotosService`, each of them implementing `IPhotosService`.

In the web api, i would inject `IPhotosService` :

```
IPhotosService _service;

public PhotosController(IPhotosService service){
   _service = service;
}
```

The web api uses token authentication with claims. So what i want to achieve, is for each user, depending on the claim he has : `type1 or type2 or type3`, the correct implementation of the service will be automatically injected rather than injecting a single service in the `startup` file.
What i want to avoid, is having one service, with a bunch of `switch` and `if` statements to return the correct data depending on user type and the roles he has.

EDIT:
some comments were wondering what's the point of three implementations, so here are more details to give it a little more sense.
The service is a job finder service, and the application has three different profiles : `candidate, employer and administration`. Each of these profiles need a proper implementation. So rather than having three methods `GetCandidateJobs, GetEmployerJobs and GetAdministrationJobs` inside the same service and switch on the user type, i preferred to have one implementation per profile type, then depending on the profile type, use the correct implementation.

Comment: review strategy pattern. I suggest that because based on what you want, the User is  not known as yet when the controller is being initialized and injected with dependencies. So what you want wont be known till within a the action well after the controller has been created and its dependencies injected.

Comment: Either that or inject a factory and resolve the service from it `photoServiceFactory.GetServiceForUser(User user)` but honestly I am not sure why you need 3 different implementation of the photos service if all you need is different credentials based on a condition

Comment: The reason this caught my attention was because I had to do all of this in a .NET 4.6 app. I did it with Windsor, then found out that I wasn't allowed to use Windsor, so I did it again with no IoC container. I ended up liking the version without Windsor a little bit more because it was simpler. Working through it again to answer this question reconfirmed that for me. It's documented [here](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/12/16/liberation-of-pure-di-mef-is-not-ioc.html).

Comment: @Nkosi you have the most appropriate answer, add it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 10):

### Without Using a Separate IoC Container

Here's an approach that's way easier than configuring your app to use another IoC container *and then* configuring that container. After working through this with Windsor this solution seems a whole lot easier.

This approach is simplest if you can use a singleton instance of each service implementation.

We'll start with an interface, some implementations, and the factory we can inject which will return an implementation selected at runtime based on some input.

```
public interface ICustomService { }
public class CustomServiceOne : ICustomService { }
public class CustomServiceTwo : ICustomService { }
public class CustomServiceThree : ICustomService { }

public interface ICustomServiceFactory
{
    ICustomService Create(string input);
}
```

Here's a really crude implementation of the factory. (Didn't use string constants, or polish it at all.)

```
public class CustomServiceFactory : ICustomServiceFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ICustomService> _services 
        = new Dictionary<string, ICustomService>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public CustomServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _services.Add("TypeOne", serviceProvider.GetService<CustomServiceOne>());
        _services.Add("TypeTwo", serviceProvider.GetService<CustomServiceTwo>());
        _services.Add("TypeThree", serviceProvider.GetService<CustomServiceThree>());
    }

    public ICustomService Create(string input)
    {
        return _services.ContainsKey(input) ? _services[input] : _services["TypeOne"];
    }
}
```

This assumes that you've already registered `CustomServiceOne`, `CustomServiceTwo`, etc. with the `IServiceCollection`. They would not be registered as interface implementations, since that's not how we're resolving them. This class will simply resolve each one and put them in a dictionary so that you can retrieve them by name.

In this case the factory method takes a string, but you could inspect any type or multiple arguments to determine which implementation to return. Even the use of a string as the dictionary key is arbitrary. And, just as an example, I provided fallback behavior to return some default implementation. It might make more sense to throw an exception instead if you can't determine the right implementation to return.

Another alternative, depending on your needs, would be to resolve the implementation within the factory when it's requested. To the extent possible I try to keep most classes stateless so that I can resolve and reuse a single instance.

To register the factory with the `IServiceCollection` at startup we would do this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICustomServiceFactory>(provider => 
    new CustomServiceFactory(provider));
```

The `IServiceProvider` will be injected into the factory when the factory is resolved, and then the factory will use it to resolve the service.

Here's the corresponding unit tests. The test method is the identical to the one used in the Windsor answer, which "proves" that we can transparently replace one factory implementation with another and change other stuff in the composition root without breaking stuff.

```
public class Tests
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<CustomServiceOne>();
        services.AddSingleton<CustomServiceTwo>();
        services.AddSingleton<CustomServiceThree>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICustomServiceFactory>(provider => 
            new CustomServiceFactory(provider));
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    [TestCase("TypeOne", typeof(CustomServiceOne))]
    [TestCase("TypeTwo", typeof(CustomServiceTwo))]
    [TestCase("TYPEThree", typeof(CustomServiceThree))]
    [TestCase("unknown", typeof(CustomServiceOne))]
    public void FactoryReturnsExpectedService(string input, Type expectedType)
    {
        var factory = _serviceProvider.GetService<ICustomServiceFactory>();
        var service = factory.Create(input);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(expectedType, service);
    }
}
```

As in the Windsor example, this is written to avoid any reference to the container outside of the composition root. If a class depends on `ICustomServiceFactory` and `ICustomService` you could switch between this implementation, the Windsor implementation, or any other implementation of the factory.

Answer (score 5):

### Using Windsor

I'm going to sidestep the questions about whether or not this makes sense in this case and just attempt to answer the question as asked:

.NET Core's IoC container isn't built particularly well for this sort of scenario. (They acknowledge this in their documentation.) You can work around it by adding another IoC container like Windsor.

The implementation ended up looking way more complicated than I would have liked, but once you get past the setup it's not bad and you get access to Windsor's features. I'm going to provide another answer that doesn't include Windsor. I had to do all of this work to see that I probably like the other approach better.

In your project, add the [Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection) NuGet package.

#### Interfaces and Implementations for Testing

For testing, I added some interfaces and implementations:

```
public interface ICustomService { }
public interface IRegisteredWithServiceCollection { }
public class CustomServiceOne : ICustomService { }
public class CustomServiceTwo : ICustomService { }
public class CustomServiceThree : ICustomService { }
public class RegisteredWithServiceCollection : IRegisteredWithServiceCollection { }
```

The intent is to create a factory that will select and return an implementation of `ICustomService` using some runtime input.

Here's an interface which will serve as a factory. This is what we can inject into a class and call at runtime to get an implementation of `ICustomService`:

```
public interface ICustomServiceFactory
{
    ICustomService Create(string input);
}
```

#### Configure the Windsor Container

Next is a class which will configure an `IWindsorContainer` to resolve dependencies:

```
public class WindsorConfiguration : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ICustomService, CustomServiceOne>().Named("TypeOne"),
            Component.For<ICustomService, CustomServiceTwo>().Named("TypeTwo"),
            Component.For<ICustomService, CustomServiceThree>().Named("TypeThree"),
            Component.For<ICustomService, CustomServiceOne>().IsDefault(),
            Component.For<ICustomServiceFactory>().AsFactory(new CustomServiceSelector())
        );
    }
}

public class CustomServiceSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    public CustomServiceSelector()
        : base(fallbackToResolveByTypeIfNameNotFound: true) { }

    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
       return (string) arguments[0];
    }
}
```

Here's what's going on in here:

- The `TypedFactoryFacility` will enable us to use Windsor's typed factories. It will create an implementation of our factory interface for us.
- We're registering three implementations of `ICustomService`. Because we're registering more than one implementation, each must have a name. When we resolve `ICustomService` we can specify a name, and it will resolve the type according to that string.
- For illustration I registered another implementation of `ICustomService` without a name. That will enable us to resolve a default implementation if we try to resolve using an unrecognized name. (Some alternatives are just throwing an exception, or returning a "null" instance of `ICustomService` or creating a class like `UnknownCustomService` that throws an exception.)
- `Component.For<ICustomServiceFactory>().AsFactory(new CustomServiceSelector())` tells the container to create a proxy class to implement `ICustomServiceFactory`. (More on that in [their documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md).)
- `CustomServiceSelector` is what takes the argument passed to the factory's `Create` method and returns the component name (TypeOne, TypeTwo, etc.) that will be used to select a component. In this case we're expecting that the argument passed to the factory will be the same as the registration name we've used. But we could replace this with other logic. Our factory could even take arguments of other types which we could inspect and determine which string to return.

#### Configure Your App To Use the Windsor Container

Now, in StartUp, modify `ConfigureServices` to return `IServiceProvider` instead of `void` and create an `IServiceProvider` that combines services registered directly with the `IServiceCollection` with those registered with the Windsor container:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Install(new WindsorConfiguration());
    return WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, services);
}
```

`container.Install(new WindsorConfiguration())` allows `WindsorConfiguration` to configure our container. We could just configure the container right in this method, but this is a nice way to keep our container configurations organized. We can create numerous `IWindsorInstaller` implementations or our own custom classes to configure the Windsor container.
`WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, services)` creates the `IServiceProvider` that uses `container` and `services`.

#### Does It Work?

I wouldn't post all this without finding out first. Here's some NUnit tests. (I usually write some basic tests for DI configuration.)

The setup creates an `IServiceProvider` similar to what would happen in the application startup. It creates a container and applies the `WindsorConfiguration`. I'm also registering a service directly with the `ServiceCollection` to make sure that the two play well together. Then I'm combining the two into an `IServiceProvider`.

Then I'm resolving an `ICustomerServiceFactory` from the `IServiceProvider` and verifying that it returns the correct implementation of `ICustomService` for each input string, including the fallback when the string isn't a recognized dependency name.
I'm also verifying that the service registered directly with `ServiceCollection` is resolved.

```
public class Tests
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<IRegisteredWithServiceCollection, RegisteredWithServiceCollection>();
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new WindsorConfiguration());
        _serviceProvider = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, services);
    }

    [TestCase("TypeOne", typeof(CustomServiceOne))]
    [TestCase("TypeTwo", typeof(CustomServiceTwo))]
    [TestCase("TYPEThree", typeof(CustomServiceThree))]
    [TestCase("unknown", typeof(CustomServiceOne))]
    public void FactoryReturnsExpectedService(string input, Type expectedType)
    {
        var factory = _serviceProvider.GetService<ICustomServiceFactory>();
        var service = factory.Create(input);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(expectedType, service);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ServiceProviderReturnsServiceRegisteredWithServiceCollection()
    {
        var service = _serviceProvider.GetService<IRegisteredWithServiceCollection>();
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<RegisteredWithServiceCollection>(service);
    }
}
```

#### Is All of This Worth It?

Now that I've figured it out, I'd probably use it if I really needed this sort of functionality. It looks worse if you're trying to assimilate both using Windsor with .NET Core *and* seeing its abstract factory implementation for the first time. [Here's another article](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/23/abstract-factory-pattern.html) with some more information on Windsor's abstract factory without all the noise about .NET Core.

Comment: Please note that the Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection is _not_ an official package. Instead, see how to use the [ASP.NET Core facility](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/aspnetcore-facility.md) in the Castle Windsor documentation.

Comment: @Steven, thanks, I'll take a look and see if I can update this.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say that the attempt to utilize dependency injection for this purpose is sub-optimal. Normally this would be handled by a Factory pattern that produces service implementations using the dreaded `if` and `switch` statements. A simple example is:

```
public interface IPhotoService { 
     Photo CreatePhoto(params);
}

public class PhotoServiceFactory {
    private readonly IPhotoService _type1;
    private readonly IPhotoService _type2;
    private readonly IPhotoService _type3;
    public PhotoServiceFactory(IDependency1 d1, IDependency2 d2, ...etc) {
        _type1 = new ConcreteServiceA(d1);
        _type2 = new ConcreteServiceB(d2);
        _type3 = new ConcreteServiceC(etc);
    }
    public IPhotoService Create(User user) {
        switch(user.Claim) {
            case ClaimEnum.Type1:
                return _type1;
            case ClaimEnum.Type2:
                return _type2;
            case ClaimEnum.Type3:
                return _type3;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public class PhotosController {
    IPhotoServiceFactory _factory;
    public PhotosController(IPhotoServiceFactory factory){
       _factory = factory;
    } 
    public IHttpActionResult GetPhoto() {
       var photoServiceToUse = _factory.Create(User);
       var photo = photoServiceToUse.CreatePhoto(params);
       return Ok(photo);
    }
}
```

Alternately just use the concrete classes as arguments in the constructor and follow a similar logic as to the above.

Comment: I don't recommend having interfaces called `IType1PhotoService`, `IType2PhotoService`, etc. that inherit `IPhotoService`. The point of the interface is that it doesn't vary according to implementation. (And, hair-splitting detail - this example *is* dependency injection, just without an IoC container.) Other than that I agree that this implementation is okay, especially since classes will depend on the factory interface which means the factory implementation can be changed if the need arises (which could feasibly never happen.)

Comment: @ScottHannen I agree with you on the point that the named interfaces is not quite the nicest thing, but I'm sacrificing a little bit of the `Interface Segregation Principal` in order to more finely support the `Liskov Substitution Prinicipal`.

Comment: If the factory is going to depend on three different types that implement the interface then they might as well be concrete types. That would eliminate the need for the extra interfaces.

Comment: I'd prefer not to instantiate the dependencies inside the factory using service locator, unless you mean to register them without interfaces at all?

Comment: Thinking it over, I'd just new up the `ConcreteTypeA`/`B`/`C` in the factory and have the interface dependencies as constructor arguments to the abstract factory. I looked up and read Ploeh blog but I very much disagree with utilizing the service locator even in a case of the "infrastructure components" as he proposes. I'd much rather consumers understand what their dependencies are then rely on the composition root at any level.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, i have created inside asp.net core console application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace CreationalPattern
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Add dependency into service collection
            var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddTransient<FordFigoFactory>()
                .AddTransient<AudiQ7Factory>();

            /* Create CarServiceFactory as singleton because it can be used across the application more frequently*/
            services.AddSingleton<ICarServiceFactory>(provider => new CarServiceFactory(provider));            

            // create a service provider from the service collection
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


            /* instantiate car*/
            var factory = serviceProvider.GetService<ICarServiceFactory>();
            var audiCar = factory.Create("audi").CreateACar("Blue");            

            Console.Read();
        }
    }


    public interface ICarServiceFactory
    {
        ICreateCars Create(string input);
    }

    public class CarServiceFactory : ICarServiceFactory
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, ICreateCars> _services
            = new Dictionary<string, ICreateCars>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        public CarServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _services.Add("ford", serviceProvider.GetService<FordFigoFactory>());
            _services.Add("audi", serviceProvider.GetService<AudiQ7Factory>());               
        }

        public ICreateCars Create(string input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input + " car is created.");
            return _services.ContainsKey(input) ? _services[input] : _services["ford"];
        }
    }


    public interface ICreateCars
    {
        Car CreateACar(string color);        

    }

    public class FordFigoFactory : ICreateCars
    {
        public Car CreateACar(string color)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FordFigo car is created with color:" + color);

            return new Fordigo { Color = color};
        }
    }

    public class AudiQ7Factory : ICreateCars
    {
        public Car CreateACar(string color)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AudiQ7 car is created with color:" + color);

            return new AudiQ7 { Color = color };
        }
    }

    public abstract class Car
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Fordigo : Car
    {
        public Fordigo()
        {
            Model = "Figo";
            Company = "Ford";
        }
    }

    public class AudiQ7 : Car
    {
        public AudiQ7()
        {
            Model = "Audi";
            Company = "Q7";
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:
To understand better try to read the program from bottom to top. We have 3 sections:

1. Car (Car, Fordigo, AudiQ7)
2. CarFactory (ICreateCars, FordFigoFactory, AudiQ7Factory)
3. CarService (ICarServiceFactory, CarServiceFactory)

In this Dependency injection is registered  as transient for Factory classes FordFigoFactory and AudiQ7Factory. And Singleton for CarServiceFactory.